# I am a dessert without tea - What am I?

Tags: riddle, rhyme

I am a body part in flames

The earth and I move the same

I am a dessert without tea

When it comes to cake, I'm not easy

**What am I?**

Overall hint:

> Each line infers a different word. Each different word is an alias of the answer.

Hint for Line 1:

> Involves an actual body part

Hint for Line 2:

> Movement is relative to the sun

Hint for Line 3:

> References an actual desert (and take the line as it sounds)

Hint for Line 4:

> There is a well known idiom that this line refers to, and a word within that idiom is the answer for this line...

Comment: Are you "desser"? :)

Comment: Haha, can you justify that? :)

Comment: @IanMacDonald Reminds me of when my choir in high school enjoyed singing the Christmas classic, "Noe".

Comment: @neminem A more puzzley title would be "abcdefghijkmnopqrstuvwxyz". ;)

Comment: Are you 'sun' ? suburn , sun and earth move the same, sun +t = nuts and finally suncake ( This is my first answer, i don't have reputation to post as answer)

Comment: Answer must be "candle".

Comment: Gâteau is the only dessert I can find with 'tea' in it. Gâu (or Gau without the accent) doesn't seem to match the rest of the clues, though.

Comment: @rybo111 It's a dessert *without* tea though

Comment: @michaelsnowden Yes, and one explanation could be that you need to remove 'tea' from a dessert name to get the answer.

Comment: @rybo111 Ahh, I see what you meant. My mistake.

Comment: Well, unfortunately I can't answer 'cuz of low reputation, but the answer seems to be Uranus/Uranium. 1. Sounds like.. You know... It's on flame after that Chili. 2. Both Earth and Uranus tilt on their orbits. 3. 'Torte' without 'T' => 'Ore'. 4. Google 'Yellowcake'.

Comment: Point of clarification: I see that there are many people saying things that are 'dessert' with two 's'. Is that what you meant to write, and not a 'desert' with on 's'? The former being a tasty treat, the latter having one of the largest in the world named "Sahara". Which is correct?

Comment: [Additional support](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=flaming%20asshole&defid=2543209) for @DaniilKorotin's [answer wrapped in a  comment](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/37252/i-am-a-dessert-without-tea-what-am-i#comment110971_37252)

Comment: Body part found in [flames](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=flame&defid=2732571) **:** colon

Answer (score 28, accepted):

What am I?

> Gun!

I am a body part in flames

> A Fire-ARM!

The earth and I move the same

> A revolver (duh... kicking myself)

I am a dessert without tea

> T-Rifle

When it comes to cake, I'm not easy

> A Piece! a term for a gun. also "A piece of cake"

Comment: Rifle is a word I'm looking for, but check the overall hint I put in the question and try again. I think you may be able to solve it now :)

Comment: @Hypern Got the first one I think!

Comment: I can verify that Line 1 = Firearm, Line 3 = Rifle, but lines 2 and 4 have two different words along the same topic, and the final answer is what all four words are.

Comment: @Hypern How's my alternative to line 4?

Comment: I can verify that Line 4 = Piece, so that leaves line 2 and the overall answer. For line 2 think of a term to describe the movement of the earth relative to the sun (as mentioned in the questions hint).

Comment: @Hypern All done! ...right?

Comment: Fantastic, well done!

Comment: Nice puzzle.  +1  Tricky but satisfying (even though I couldn't quite do it without the hints!)

Answer (score 31):

OK.  So maybe it's

I am a body part in flames

> my ears are burning

The earth and I move the same

> Keep your ear to the ground?

I am a dessert without tea

> A multi T-Ear cake?

When it comes to cake, I'm not easy

> Ear... Something...

What am I?

> Probably not "Ears"

Comment: Hilarious answer, but its not ears

Comment: How about elephant ears, aka palmiers, for the dessert?  That gets you pretty close.

Answer (score 21):

You are

> the sun

I am a body part in flames

> you can get sunburn

The earth and I move the same

> earth orbits the sun, the sun orbits around the center of the milky way

I am a dessert without tea

> suncake is a Chinese dessert, usually eaten with tea, but can be dissolved in hot water instead (according to Wikipedia)

When it comes to cake, I'm not easy

> I looked up a recipe and it looks like suncake a pain to make... I dunno, maybe it's a hint that despite the name, it is not a 'piece of cake'?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange.  I'm not convinced that this answer is correct, but it is presented and reasoned better than most first answers — good job!

Comment: For the first hint: your answer is itself a body, a large part in flames.

Comment: The answer isn't sun but when it comes to cake, you said something that is along the right lines

Answer (score 12):

Are you

> an ore, or more specifically, uranium?

I am a body part in flames

> *nothing yet... searching for a pun...*

The earth and I move the same

> Ores are found in the earth

I am a dessert without tea

> a dessert without *t*: "torte" becomes "ore"

When it comes to cake, I'm not easy

> [Yellowcake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yellowcake) is extracted from ore. It is hard, i.e. "not easy".

Comment: I like your answer, if there was a comma between body and part, it could be I am a body (when it is whole), part in flames (fission causes big boom boom) Definitely a cool answer IMO

Comment: You are going along the right lines for the dessert without tea, although that's not quite the dessert I had in mind. The answer is neither ore nor uranium though.

Answer (score 10):

Are you:

> Lava

I am a body part in flames

> Lava is molten rock, a part of the earth in flames.

The earth and I move the same

> Lava is formed in the interior of the earth, moving with the earth's movements.

I am a dessert without tea

> Lava cake is a dessert with no "t" in it.

When it comes to cake, I'm not easy

> Lava cake is tricky to make.

Comment: Good idea but lava is not the answer

Answer (score 7):

Are you

> Pi(e)?

I am a body part in flames

> eating Pie can give you heartburn? Building off of Brent's earlier suggestion

The earth and I move the same

> The earth is round, pi has to do with circles

I am a dessert without tea

> Pie is generally served without tea

When it comes to cake, I'm not easy

> Easy as pie is a common idiom

What am I?

Comment: "The earth is round, pi has to do with circles" +1 for effort

Comment: The answer is not pi(e)

Answer (score 4):

You are a:

> Yule log

I am a body part in flames

> From dictionary: a large log traditionally burned in the fireplace on Christmas Eve.

The earth and I move the same

> The log is burned, and the dessert is served, typically once a year (Christmas), and the earth goes around the sun once a year.

I am a dessert without tea

> It is a dessert and has no 'T' in it.

When it comes to cake, I'm not easy

> This is a fairly complicated cake to make that requires a special mix for the filling, then it's rolled, and then often decorated to look like a log.

Comment: Welcome to puzzling.SE. Please explain your answer, as in why do you think it suffices the lines given in question :)

Comment: I don't know how yule log equates to a body part :)

Answer (score 3):

A long shot. Are you

> Heart?

I am a body part in flames

> Heartburn

The earth and I move the same

> you 'feel the earth move' when you loose your heart

I am a dessert without tea

> I said it was a long shot.

When it comes to cake, I'm not easy

> heart cake?

Comment: Its not a heart, but you have the right kind of idea for line 1.

Comment: I thought the same, also because 'earth' is an anagram! Got stuck googling 'heart cake'!

Comment: @Arth  That's a good earth connection! +1  Too bad it's not this :P

Answer (score 3):

Here's another stretch. What am I?

> It's some sort of delicious biscuit. - Bernard Black

I am a body part in flames

> I interpret this as saying that the speaker is a body and part of said body is in flames, or baked. It may be that there is a chocolate covering or a layer of custard or jam, but it's more than just straight from the oven.

The earth and I move the same

> Biscuits start as a mixture of ingredients, as molten Biscuits. They then harden and are covered with other things, just as the earth's crust forms and is covered in water, vegetation, and mini-malls.

I am a dessert without tea

> Without tea, a biscuit is just desert.

When it comes to cake, I'm not easy

> This comes from the phrase "Piece of cake," which means easy. Biscuits originate partially from hardtack, and few are as chewy as an average American cookie (as far as I'm aware). The conclusion is that biscuits are harder than cake.

Comment: You came up with what I was hinting towards in the final line, but not the correct answer. I added hints to the question to help solve the riddle.

Comment: Huzzah for Black Books quotes!

Answer (score 3):

Maybe I'm

> Stomach

Body part in flame

> Acidity Burns

The earth and I move the same

> The digestive system of most people work on a daily basis

I am dessert without tea

> Maybe that you don'e eat dessert with tea, because that'll cause Acidity

When it comes to cake I'm not easy

> If you eat quite a lot of cake, you'll get burns and indigestion

It's just a guess

Comment: "Gut" without "t" is gu, a famous brand of desserts. Or is that reaching? :)

Comment: I didn't knew about that

Comment: I think the link between the earth's movements and the stomach is a little bit weak but interesting answer :)

Comment: There process is known as m movement of bowels

Answer (score 3):

Are you...

> Frost?

I am a body part in flames

> Frostbite is a type of burn on your body parts

The Earth and I move the same

> Permafrost in the Earth's surface layer

I am a dessert without tea

> Not entirely sure, maybe a Frosty like from Wendy's?

When it comes to cake I'm not easy

> Frosting cakes is quite difficult work

Comment: Its not frost, I have added some hints to help solve the riddle

Answer (score 2):

Guess

> Pig's Blood Cake

I am a body part in flames

> blood can boil or hot blooded

The earth and I move the same

> The blood circles through the body as the earth orbits the sun

I am a dessert without tea

> Pig's Blood Cake doesn't have a "T" or served with tea

When it comes to cake, I'm not easy

> Cooking anything with blood isn't easy because it spoils quickly

Comment: Interesting idea, but its not blood.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another long shot. Are you

> eyes?

I am a body part in flames

> Eyes can burn if you get something in them

The earth and I move the same

> Both are spherical and can rotate? Not a solid explanation

I am a dessert without tea

> Most things that are iced (since 'ice' sounds very much like 'eyes', also a stretch) would be considered desserts, but not iced tea

When it comes to cake, I'm not easy

> It's not easy to ice a cake?

Comment: You seem to have switched answer between the first two and last two lines..

Comment: Yea referring to 'eyes' sounding very similar to 'ice'. Like I said, a long shot.

Comment: Eyes is not the answer

Answer (score 1):

Are you

> Baked Alaska?

I am a body part in flames

> Baked Alaska is lit aflame

The earth and I move the same

> Alaska is a territory on planet earth

I am a dessert without tea

> Ice and tea normally don't go well together (unless it's iced tea)
>  (Not too sure on this one)

When it comes to cake, I'm not easy

> Baked Alaska is rather difficult to make (compared to other cakes) (also, baked ice!)

Answer (score 1):

You are a:

> Tongue

I am a body part in flames

> The tongue can tell lies, there's also a scriptural reference in James that sort of refer to this.

The earth and I move the same

> Your tongue moves with you on the earth while it moves ... so it's moving too.

I am a dessert without tea

> If you try to say "dessert" only the "T" requires the teeth to pronounce. Everything else is more or less the tongue.

When it comes to cake, I'm not easy

> Have you tried to resist cake? Your taste buds love it. Thus, it's not easy. :)

Answer (score 1):

### Did you get the boose?

I am a body part in flames

> Did you get a boose (drunk)? :p. Liver is responsible of getting excess alcohol (a flammable) from your body.

The earth and I move the same

> Searching an explanation for this one... But when you get drunk it doesn't really matter what is moving and what is not.

I am a dessert without tea

> Liver cake, a dessert without (t). Of course, you had it with alcohol!

When it comes to cake, I'm not easy

> [Liver cake](http://www.hearingdogs.org.uk/training-our-puppies/dog-treat-recipes/liver-cake/)? Disgusting just by the name IMO.

What am I?

> A liver

Answer (score 0):

Are you

> Talk (or talking).

I am a body part in flames

> Talking about someone makes their ears burn.

The earth and I move the same

> The earth moves in circle, people talk in circles.

I am a dessert without tea

> Talk for dessert instead of drinking tea.

When it comes to cake, I'm not easy

> Hard to talk with cake in your mouth

Answer (score -1):

Are you

> an apple?

I am a body part in flames

> The apple of one's eye, a phrase for describing something the person prizes.  Eyes are also described as shining or bright when someone's enthusiastic, or alight or even burning with passion or certainty.  The eyes burn, for the apple of one's eye.

The earth and I move the same

> Maybe myths, like Johnny Appleseed or the garden of Eden, where apples are linked to people's relations to the earth.  Maybe it is talking about growing seasons, and apple orchards - moving through the seasons (like the earth) to produce fruit.

I am a dessert without tea

> Apple tea!  Fruit by itself can be a dessert - an apple by itself, or with a fruit plate or a fruit and cheese platter or baked apples or a boiled apple pudding.  Turkish apple tea is also quite popular and very good - but once tea has been added, it is a beverage and no longer a dessert.

When it comes to cake, I'm not easy

> The phrase is 'easy as pie' - and apple pie is the quintessential pie, after all the phrase is 'as American as apple pie' for a reason.  Alternatively, if the line is a little more literal, it might refer to apple-cake, of which there are many recipes, and which are tasty but not usually easy to balance.

Edit - apparently I took long enough answering to miss out on the hints... I'm probably not right, then.  Ah, well.